# Active Directory Self Service

Tags: active-directory

Up until now, we have only needed to include about half of our organization in Active Directory (about 1000 users give or take).  There is a new application being released that is to be used by every employee in our organization (about 2000 in total = 1000 additional users).

Our help desk and active directory manager are expressing concerns about being overwhelmed with keeping AD up to date.  They are especially concerned about password resets since these additional users will only be using one application and not logging in all day every day.

We are looking at AD self service solutions.  We could code one ourselves or use an existing solution.  Does anyone out there have any experience with AD self service products (free or commercial)?

Comment: For one of those questions...yes, I failed to accept an answer and I have remedied the situation for that instance.  For the others, there was no acceptable answer.  Just because there are proposed answers does not mean one of them is an actual workable solution.  Therefore, no answer was accepted nor will one be accepted unless someone proposes a proper solution.

Comment: @NYSystemsAnalyst:  So none of those questions have been resolved by you?

Comment: Of the remaining three, the certificate one is unresolved.  The IIS one required a re-build of the server (not a solution).  The printer issue resulted in purchasing a new printer (again, not a solution).  Now, unless you have something constructive to add regarding THIS question, please do not add anymore useless comments.

Comment: [Possible duplicate?](http://serverfault.com/questions/186560/how-to-reduce-our-ad-account-creation-and-maintenance-requests-and-work-load)

Comment: Product recommendation questions are off topic per the FAQ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have experience with [myPassword](http://www.namescape.com/Products/myPassword.aspx), which does web-based password resets, password changes and account unlocking. It works pretty well for us with very little administrative overhead. It works by having users setup a profile with a series of "security questions" and then uses those to verify a user before allowing them to do anything with their account. It is a commercial product, but I am not sure of pricing details since that is handled by other people.

The same company has another product called rDirectory that has even more self-service capabilities, but I am unfamiliar with that.

Comment: This looks interesting, though I don't see any pricing info on their website.  I'll be passing it on to my manager.

Comment: @NYSystemsAnalyst: I know (for myPassword at least) the pricing is per user account, but I am unsure of what the amount per user is, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I have not used this specific product, but I have used another product by these guys and was very happy with it.

[ADSelfService Plus](http://www.manageengine.com/products/self-service-password/index.html)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but the pricing (~$1500 / year) is more than we can afford at this time.